# How can I access to page.open function result? phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, phantomjs-node

How can I get access to the result that is returned from the callback?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {
    // code
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear currently what you ask. Is it a PhantomJS script? Is it a node.js script? What result do you need? Where do you want to return it to?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a screenshot of the page, use `page.render('example.pdf')`. If you need the raw html data use `page.evaluate(function(){
   return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
},function(rawData){
console.log(rawData);})`

Comment: I use page.evaluate and I receive some result. But I want to use it outside of page.open

Comment: do you want to use it outside `page.evaluate` or`page.open`?

Comment: Outside page.open

Comment: Just declare a public variable and assign the return value to the variable.